# Is there an EOS mainnet - similar to the Ethereum Public Network?

Tags: nodeos

I have been a little confused by the structure of EOS. If I state how I use Ethereum, perhaps someone can draw a parallel to EOS.

I use the mainnet in Ethereum for production level work and deploy in the normal way. I test using Ropsten etc. I also create my own networks for some testing just using geth and linking nodes.

I had believed EOS was focused around private networks, but someone told me it has a mainnet. Is this similar to the Ethereum one, ie one network which is supposed to a "code is law" type of concept?

I would appreciate any clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it has a mainnet :-)

You can check tx, blocks, accounts here :

https://www.cypherblock.io/

https://eosflare.io/

The chainId is : aca376f206b8fc25a6ed44dbdc66547c36c6c33e3a119ffbeaef943642f0e906